# Having Multiple Alignments In Same TextArea

Tags: java, swing, jframe, document, jtextarea

I am making Calculator app.
I want digits (Number)to be written on the right side of textArea  and signs(+,-,/,*) on the left side of same textArea.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can have multiple alignments inside textarea, but instead you can use JTextPane here is an exemple [Multiple Alignement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25682219/java-is-it-possible-to-define-different-alignment-in-jtextpane) or create your own calculator display :

1-create a container (BorderLayout for exemple)

2-add two JLabels to the container to display text dynamically

3-make the first JLabel with right Alignement `setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT)`

4-make the second JLabel with left Alignement
`setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT)`

I hope this is what you are looking for, after all this is just a suggestion !

Comment: Thanks but sorry this is not the answer I am looking for, I want to display sign as well number in same textarea or textpane .But I will use your suggestion as an alternative plan.